# Generar tabla de doble entrada con datos diferentes

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy utilizando R-exams y quiero generar una tabla de doble entrada, pero cada vez con un grupo distinto de valores (propongo 5 distintos: datos1,datos2,datos3,datos4,datos5), pero no funciona, ni con un contador, ni con "sample".

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?
Gracias

```
datos1 = c(0 , 2 , 4 , 2, 4 , 8, 13, 6, 12)
datos2 = c(11 , 2 , 4 , 2, 4 , 8, 3, 6, 12)
datos3 = c(12 , 2 , 14 , 2, 4 , 28, 3, 6, 12)
datos4 = c(13 , 2 , 4 , 2, 4 , 8, 3, 6, 12)
datos5 = c(1 , 2 , 4 , 22, 4 , 8, 3, 6, 12)

w9 <- sample(c(datos1, datos2, datos3, datos4, datos5),1)


tabla = cbind (expand.grid (list (Y = c ("3","5","6") ,
X = c ("6","8","9"))), count = w9)
ftable (xtabs(count ∼ Y + X, tabla ))
```

Comment: Bienvenida Amelia a SO en Español. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo  de lo que quieres obtener? Eso ayudaría mucho que consigas una respuesta adecuada. Puedes editar tu pregunta en cualquier momento con el enlace "Editar" que se encuentra debajo.

Comment: Si w9 es por ejemplo datos5, la salida por filas es 1 22 3, 2 4 6 and 4 8 12.  Quiero que de un conjunto de 5 posibles vectores, elegir aleatoriamente un grupo (ya sea datos1, datos2 o....datos5). No quiero poner concretamente un grupo.
Al poner que elija aleatoriamente uno de los grupos la salida es una matriz por filas con todo 1 o 2 o 3....., es decir 1 1 1, 1 1 1, 1 1 1, que no es correcto, de acuerdo con los valores de los vectores.

Comment: ¿Entonces querrías elegir aleatoriamente uno de los vectores y usarlo para algo?  Podrías hacer algo similar a lo que probaste con `c()` pero haciendo una lista. Algo así: `w9 <- unlist(sample(list(datos1, datos2, datos3, datos4, datos5),1))` . Uso el unlist por que sino obtendrías un vector dentro de una lista y entiendo que lo que quieres es el vector directo.

Comment: La solución es como dices: w9 <- sample(list(datos1, datos2, datos3, datos4, datos5), 1)
w9 <- unlist(w9) Muchas gracias